# Golang Tour Webcrawler exercise

Tags: beginner, concurrency, go

I am new in Go and for study I have to hold a presentation about concurrency in Go. I think the Golang Tour - Webcrawler exercise is a nice example to talk about that. Before I do that, it would be nice if anybody could verify if this solution fits. I assume it is correct but perhaps I have missed anything or any of you have a better alternative.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

/*
 * Data and Types
 * ===================================================================================
 */
var fetched map[string]bool    // Map of fetched URLs -> true: fetched
var lock sync.Mutex            // locks write access to fetched-map
var urlChan chan string        // Channel to Write fetched URL

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
/*
 * End Data and Types
 * ===================================================================================
 */

/*
 * Webcrawler implementation
 * ===================================================================================
 */
func waitUntilDone(d int) {

    fMap := make(map[string]string)

    for i := 0; i < d; i++ {
        fMap[<-urlChan] = strconv.Itoa(time.Now().Nanosecond())
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Fetch stats")
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")
    for k, v := range fMap {
        fmt.Println("Fetched: " + k + " after: " + v + " ns")
    }
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")
    fmt.Println()

}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    var str string
    var strArr [] string
    var err error

    if fetched[url] {
        // already fetched?
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("already fetched: %s this will be ignored", url)

    }else if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        str, strArr, err = res.body, res.urls, nil
        urlChan <- url

    }else {
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
    }

    return str, strArr, err
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, goRoutNum int) {

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    // Start fetching url concurrently
    fmt.Println("Goroutine " + strconv.Itoa(goRoutNum) + " is fetching: " + url)
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Lock map
    lock.Lock()
    fetched[url] = true

    // Unlock
    lock.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    for i, u := range urls {
        go func(url string, goRoutNumber int) {
            Crawl(url, depth - 1, fetcher, goRoutNumber)
        }(u, i + 1)
    }
    return
}

func StartCrawling(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Start crawling ...")
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")

    go func(u string, i int, f Fetcher) {
        Crawl(u, i, f, 0)

    }(url, depth, fetcher)
}
/*
 * End Webcrawler implementation
 * ===================================================================================
 */


/*
 * Main
 * ====================================================================
 */
func main() {

    depth := len(fetcher)
    fetched = make(map[string]bool)
    url := "http://golang.org/"
    urlChan = make(chan string, len(fetcher))
    go StartCrawling(url, depth, fetcher)
    waitUntilDone(depth)

}

/*
 * End Main
 * =====================================================================
 */
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GHHt5I162o)

[Exercise link](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Hello there - like I said before, please do not update your question with "the new, improved code". If you just want to share your improvements, answer your own question and describe what steps you took to make it better. If you want to have your newly improved code reviewed, make a follow-up question and link back to this one. If you don't feel like writing a whole answer to share your newly improved code, just write a comment with the link to the new playground.

Answer (score 7):

Combine the mutex with the thing it is locking into a single struct. Often mutex elements of a struct are unnamed, since you only need to lock and unlock the whole thing

```
type SafeMap struct {
  sync.Mutex
  URLs map[string]bool
}
```

which you can then use like so:

```
url := "http://some_example.com"
fetched := SafeMap{URLs:map[string]bool{}}
fetched.Lock()
fetched.URLs[url] = true
fetched.Unlock()
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I have refactored some code and put in the suggestion above

I changed:

```
func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    var str string
    var strArr [] string
    var err error

    if fetched[url] {
        // already fetched?
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("already fetched: %s this will be ignored", url)

    }else if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        str, strArr, err = res.body, res.urls, nil
        urlChan <- url

    }else {
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
    }

    return str, strArr, err
}
```

To:

```
func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    var str string
    var strArr [] string
    var err error

    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        str, strArr, err = res.body, res.urls, nil
        urlChan <- url

    }else {
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
    }

    return str, strArr, err
}
```

And:

```
// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, goRoutNum int) {

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    // Start fetching url concurrently
    fmt.Println("Goroutine " + strconv.Itoa(goRoutNum) + " is fetching: " + url)
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Lock map
    lock.Lock()
    fetched[url] = true

    // Unlock
    lock.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    for i, u := range urls {
        go func(url string, goRoutNumber int) {
            Crawl(url, depth - 1, fetcher, goRoutNumber)
        }(u, i + 1)
    }
    return
}
```

To:

```
// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, goRoutNum int) {

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    var body string; var urls [] string; var err error

    // lock
    safeMap.Lock()
    if safeMap.URLs[url] { //already fetched?
        body, urls, err =
            "", nil, fmt.Errorf("already fetched: %s this will be ignored", url)
        fmt.Println(err)
        safeMap.Unlock()
        return
    }
    safeMap.URLs[url] = true
    safeMap.Unlock()
    // Start fetching url concurrentl
    fmt.Println("Goroutine " + strconv.Itoa(goRoutNum) + " is fetching: " + url)
    body, urls, err = fetcher.Fetch(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Lock map
    safeMap.Lock()
    safeMap.URLs[url] = true

    // Unlock
    safeMap.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    for i, u := range urls {
        go func(url string, goRoutNumber int) {
            Crawl(url, depth - 1, fetcher, goRoutNumber)
        }(u, i + 1)
    }
    return
}
```

Whole updated Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

/*
 * Data and Types
 * ===================================================================================
 */
type SafeMap struct{
    sync.Mutex                      // locks write access to fetched-map
    URLs map[string]bool    // Map of fetched URLs -> true: fetched
}

var urlChan chan string        // Channel to Write fetched URL
var safeMap SafeMap

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
/*
 * End Data and Types
 * ===================================================================================
 */

/*
 * Webcrawler implementation
 * ===================================================================================
 */
func waitUntilDone(d int) {

    fMap := make(map[string]string)

    for i := 0; i < d; i++ {
        fMap[<-urlChan] = strconv.Itoa(time.Now().Nanosecond())
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Fetch stats")
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")
    for k, v := range fMap {
        fmt.Println("Fetched: " + k + " after: " + v + " ns")
    }
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")
    fmt.Println()

}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    var str string
    var strArr [] string
    var err error

    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        str, strArr, err = res.body, res.urls, nil
        urlChan <- url

    }else {
        str, strArr, err = "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
    }

    return str, strArr, err
}


// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, goRoutNum int) {

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    var body string; var urls [] string; var err error

    // lock
    safeMap.Lock()
    if safeMap.URLs[url] {
        body, urls, err =
            "", nil, fmt.Errorf("already fetched: %s this will be ignored", url)
        fmt.Println(err)
        safeMap.Unlock()
        return
    }
    safeMap.URLs[url] = true
    safeMap.Unlock()
    // Start fetching url concurrentl
    fmt.Println("Goroutine " + strconv.Itoa(goRoutNum) + " is fetching: " + url)
    body, urls, err = fetcher.Fetch(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Lock map
    safeMap.Lock()
    safeMap.URLs[url] = true

    // Unlock
    safeMap.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    for i, u := range urls {
        go func(url string, goRoutNumber int) {
            Crawl(url, depth - 1, fetcher, goRoutNumber)
        }(u, i + 1)
    }
    return
}

func StartCrawling(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Start crawling ...")
    fmt.Println("==================================================================")

    go func(u string, i int, f Fetcher) {
        Crawl(u, i, f, 0)

    }(url, depth, fetcher)
}
/*
 * End Webcrawler implementation
 * ===================================================================================
 */


/*
 * Main
 * ====================================================================
 */
func main() {

    depth := len(fetcher)
    safeMap = SafeMap{URLs:map[string]bool{}}
    //safeMap = SafeMap{Urls: make(map[string]bool)}
    url := "http://golang.org/"
    urlChan = make(chan string, len(fetcher))
    go StartCrawling(url, depth, fetcher)
    waitUntilDone(depth)

}

/*
 * End Main
 * =====================================================================
 */
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2dPgUKshm6
Exercise: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to me to use an algorithm that relies on knowing exactly how many URLs will need to be fetched.

You use `len(fetcher)` to determine your starting depth as well as the buffer size for the `urlChan`.  So basically you're using what you know about the mock data to write code that would need to be deployed on the unknowable internet.

Thanks for sharing your solution.  If you have any feedback about mine (written before I saw this), I'd be happy to hear it: [My solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254295/2-weeks-into-go-golang-tour-webcrawler-exercise)